# Insert blank row between rows with new value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 column NAMES & MYDATA. Column NAMES has names of clients and MYDATA has list of their purchases:

```
**NAMES**   **MYDATA**
AMIT    PEPSI
AMIT    COKE
AMIT    LIMCA
JOHN    PEPSI
JOHN    COKE
PAUL    COKE
PAUL    COKE
JACK    PEPSI
JACK    LIMCA
```

**I want following steps:**

a) Use SELECT statement and get the required data and

b) Convert MYDATA it to UNHEX (Insensitive case)

c) Sort out put as per NAMES column

d) Enter a new blank row in the out put, whenever a New value is seen in column NAMES

**DESIRED results:**

```
**NAMES**   **MYDATA**
AMIT    PEPSI
AMIT    COKE
AMIT    LIMCA
<BLANK ROW> <BLANK ROW>
JOHN    PEPSI
JOHN    COKE
<BLANK ROW> <BLANK ROW>
PAUL    COKE
PAUL    COKE
<BLANK ROW> <BLANK ROW>
JACK    PEPSI
JACK    LIMCA
```

I have been able to achieve steps a,b,c with below stated command. How can I achieve step 4 for desired results?

```
SELECT NAMES, CAST(UNHEX( MYDATA) AS CHAR) FROM databasename.tablename
WHERE
    LOWER(CAST(UNHEX(USER_DATA) AS CHAR)) LIKE '%jack%'
    OR LOWER(CAST(UNHEX(USER_DATA) AS CHAR)) LIKE '%amit%'
order by NAMES;
```

Comment: Your query produces nothing at all - have you posted the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really mysql's job to pretty print but you can achieve this with a union to some dummy value.

```
select case when mydata = 'XXXXX' then '' else names end as name,
case when mydata = 'XXXXX' then '' else mydata end as value
from
(
select t.* 
from t
union
select distinct names, 'XXXXX' 
from t
) s 
order by names,mydata
```

Comment: "`It's not really mysql's job to pretty print`". Exactly.